# Data lost in SQL Server using application in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database in a SQL Server and I am inserting data using an application in C#.

The problem is, when I insert data the data isn't stored in right column.

This is my code:

```
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO pointagee (Nom_employe, Date_Heure , Matin, Midi, apresmidi, Soir) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ?, ?, ?);";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("nom", nom_employe);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", date_heure);

    if (matin == null)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("matin", "NULL");
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("matin", matin);
    }
    if (midi == null)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("midi", "NULL");
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("midi", midi);
    }
    if (Apresmidi == null)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("apresmidi", "NULL");
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("apresmidi", Apresmidi);
    }
    if (Soir == null)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("soir", "NULL");
    }
    else
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("soir", Soir);
    }
```

And this is an example in the database:

These are the columns:

```
ID_employe   Nom_employe       Date_Heure   Matin          Midi         apresmidi        Soir                               

1           26/02/2020        henry        26/02/2020     12:12:12      NULL             NULL
```

Because of this problem this a NULL value is lost.

Comment: Can you please explain the problem in more detail, I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: I'm confused. Is the stored procedure a SQL stored procedure or is it what you have here?? Also, can we PLEASE stop using `AddWithValue`

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to store the literal value "NULL"? It looks like you need an actual `NULL`.

Comment: When you need to store an actual NULL value, insert DBNull.Value instead.

Comment: yes bu the problem is it wont actually insert null so i have to do it like this "NULL"

Comment: Sorry i tried to be as specifix as possible

Comment: the problem is i have the date stored in Nom_employe for no Reason idk why and it is actually Moving all other values to the right and in this case a have a lost value

Comment: And trying to use DBnull i get the Following error : DBnull doesnt exists in this context

Comment: and i tried like this aswell : command.Parameters.Add("@Issdfsd", OdbcType.Text).Value = nom_employe;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Name", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = date_heure;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Pass", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = matin;
               // command.Parameters.Add("@Email", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = midi;
                //command.Parameters.Add("@Address", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Apresmidi;
               // command.Parameters.Add("@Age", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Soir;*/ and it didn't work that's why i use adwithvalue

Comment: also im using ODBC so i can't use tags

Comment: To explain better the problem is : in th column Nom_ employe it's inserted a date wich i didn't insert as you can see on the c# code and that  value is Moving every othe value to the right column and the lase value on the table is lost because of that !

Comment: I fixed it thanks everyone have a nice day